# Spring Security - Authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security and I'm having episodes of difficulties configuring my application and I hope you all are generous enough to assist me.

I believe I may have configured Spring Security however the dilemma here is that, my authentication is coming from the database. My intended authentication mechanism for now, is the classical username and hashed password. By the time, I completed my configuration and re-launched the application, I'm reading a 403 error. Which tells me, I may have just successfully completed the security set-up but what's my username and password? I'm using an H2 database so these details are deleted at each re-start of the application. Am I supposed to manually create a user in the database via an insert statement? Please advice.

I'm trying to read and write users to and from the database. I tried allowing all requests to register and login at the launch but still not working. Attached is my security configurations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityBasicAuthConfig {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService user;

   @Bean
   public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
   
   @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("api/v1/registration/add")
            .permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()).csrf().disable().build();
    }

   @Bean
   public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
   {
       return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }

   @Bean
   AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() 
   {
       DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
       provider.setUserDetailsService(user);
       provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
       return provider;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add your UserDetailsService implementation

Comment: there are several unknowns in your question you write `hashed passwords` there are several different hashes, argon2, bcrypt, md5, sha2 etc. You have added CORS for an MVC application, is this an MVC application? if not you configure CORS differently, please read the spring security docs CORS chapter. Have you implemented a `UserDetailsService`if so were is that code? Were is your registration code? and also you should enable `DEBUG` logs and edit your question to include them so we can see what your server is doing.

Answer (score -1):

Try
Account name:user
And when you run spring boot, there is one line one your console like this:
Using generated security password: 4925b629-d788-418b-90db-fb3877ba8706
See if this works!

Comment: the default spring security password is only printed if you dont override the default spring security configuration which the question asker clearly has done.